ValueError: Unable to synchronously create dataset (name already exists)
When I tried to save the model as h5
caption_model.save("/kaggle/working/mymodel.h5")

This erorr appeared to me
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[19], line 1
----> 1 caption_model.save("/kaggle/working/mymodel.h5")

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py:122, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
    119     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
    120     # To get the full stack trace, call:
    121     # `keras.config.disable_traceback_filtering()`
--> 122     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    123 finally:
    124     del filtered_tb

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/h5py/_hl/group.py:183, in Group.create_dataset(self, name, shape, dtype, data, **kwds)
    180         parent_path, name = name.rsplit(b'/', 1)
    181         group = self.require_group(parent_path)
--> 183 dsid = dataset.make_new_dset(group, shape, dtype, data, name, **kwds)
    184 dset = dataset.Dataset(dsid)
    185 return dset

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/h5py/_hl/dataset.py:163, in make_new_dset(parent, shape, dtype, data, name, chunks, compression, shuffle, fletcher32, maxshape, compression_opts, fillvalue, scaleoffset, track_times, external, track_order, dcpl, dapl, efile_prefix, virtual_prefix, allow_unknown_filter, rdcc_nslots, rdcc_nbytes, rdcc_w0)
    160 else:
    161     sid = h5s.create_simple(shape, maxshape)
--> 163 dset_id = h5d.create(parent.id, name, tid, sid, dcpl=dcpl, dapl=dapl)
    165 if (data is not None) and (not isinstance(data, Empty)):
    166     dset_id.write(h5s.ALL, h5s.ALL, data)

File h5py/_objects.pyx:54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

File h5py/_objects.pyx:55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

File h5py/h5d.pyx:137, in h5py.h5d.create()

ValueError: Unable to synchronously create dataset (name already exists)

Has any of you encountered this problem before or knows how to solve it?
Thank you

I don't know your model structure, but if you use tf.Variable in model, this problem may arise.
class Re(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.gamma = tf.Variable(1.0, trainable=True, dtype=tf.float32)
        print(self.gamma.name)

    def call(self, x, training=None, **kwargs):
        x = self.gamma * x
        return x

class Generator(Model):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.layer = Sequential([Re() for _ in range(2)])

    def call(self, x, training=None, **kwargs):
        x = self.layer(x, training=training)
        return x

The result of the print is
Variable:0
Variable:0

They have the same name, resulting in a naming conflict.
So define variables under namescope in the current layer
class Re(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        with tf.name_scope(self.name_scope()):
            self.gamma = tf.Variable(1.0, trainable=True, dtype=tf.float32)
        print(self.gamma.name)

    def call(self, x, training=None, **kwargs):
        x = self.gamma * x
        return x

re/Variable:0
re_1/Variable:0

Tip: The naming rule for the layer is {class_name.lower()}_{order} like re_1
However if you use:
class Re(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.gamma = tf.Variable(1.0, trainable=True, dtype=tf.float32)
        print(self.gamma.name)

    def call(self, x, training=None, **kwargs):
        x = self.gamma * x
        return x


class Generator(Model):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.layer1 = Re()
        self.layer2 = Re()

    def call(self, x, training=None, **kwargs):
        x = self.layer1(x, training=training)
        x = self.layer2(x, training=training)
        return x

Variable:0
Variable:0

this problem can also be solved. idk why.
